# What approach is good for US State ListBox/DropDownList

Tags: object, binding, listbox, datatable, states

What is the best approach to bind US State in WPF (in ListBox or in DropDownList)? Should I use DataTable to bind this data? Is binding DataTable to WPF object right programming approach? Or Should I use class/object. I mean get data from database and convert it to Generic Object List and then bind this list to WPF object?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class States
    {
        private string name;  
        public string Name    
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
        }

        private string id;  
        public string Id  
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }
        }
    }

        List<States> states = new List<States>();

        //get from database


        foreach( states DataSource)
        {
            name = "Alabama";
            id = "1";
        }

        // next Cache list of states for better performance
```

Many ways... 
One approach is to use a list class. get from data source, next cache for better performance.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. Below is my code. I used while(rdr.read()) to read data from the reader and add to List object. BUT it really degraded performance. 
How I noticed that performance is degraded?
I used to bind my State list box with DataTable and now tried with List object. I can literally see it takes almost two seconds while with DataTable it was only in eye blink.

Any suggestion??

Comment: ADO.Net has a lot of built in overhead when reading from a database. Using a DataAdapter which binds to a DataSet, which then binds to DataTable has too many steps and slow performance. 

Using just the SQLCommand is lighter and faster and requires less to connect.

The first approach is easier to use for beginners.

Good coding standards is to use less code as possible, and connect and return only the data you need from the Database. 

But for data from DB that will be used and won't change. I recommend Caching it.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation. But I am still confuse. I understand about DataAdpater and DataSet which I definitely don't want to use. As you explained I will go for SQL Command but don't understand what you mean by caching it. Can you please refer any website? Does cache mean using any collection?? Please advice.

Comment: Caching is used to store data into memory. For example lets say you want to show a list of the 50 states on 2 separate web pages. You can make 1 call to the database and store the results into the cache memory. So the next time you load the page, you will get the results from the cache and not the database. That will improve performance greatly. No need to hit the database over and over again. Pulling data from the server memory is much faster.

Comment: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx]        [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972379.aspx]